# Cannot initialize factory bot factories in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, factory-bot, rails-engines

I have a Rails 5.2 engine, and I need to have some system (with capybara) test to run on it.
I'm also using factories for that, with the `factory_bot_rails` gem.

To run the test, I need to use the command `rails test:app:system`, since the standard `rails test:system` gives an error, since it's an engine.
So the system test is run in the context of the dummy app.

Before starting it gives an error of `Factory xxxx not initialized`, I suppose because all the factories are in `test/factories`, and the dummy app is in `test/dummy` and can't load them.

How can i run my system test for the engine?
I think my options are run the system test in the engine context, or load the factories into the dummy...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you are right in that you would need to run the test suite within the engine context.

I believe you need to:

```
# rails_helper.rb or spec_helper.rb

require 'factory_bot_rails'
```

If things are still wonky, should be able to add the exact directory with:

```
require 'factory_bot_rails'

FactoryBot.definition_file_paths << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'factories')
FactoryBot.find_definitions
```

Explained here https://www.hocnest.com/blog/testing-an-engine-with-rspec/

Also, ensure you have included `config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods` in your `rails_helper.rb`